# Second partial derivation of vector function and taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I have vector function:
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x) \\
(R+r\cos(y))\sin(x) \\
r\sin(y) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have done Jacobian of that function:
$$
f'(x,y) =
\begin{pmatrix}
(R+r\cos(y))\cdot(-\sin(x)) & r\cos(x)(-\sin(y)) \\
(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x) & r\sin(x)(-\sin(y)) \\
0 & r\cos(y)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What about second partial derivation? I cannot do hessian, because it would have to be cubical like matrix.

I know i have to do 2nd par. deriv. for each component separately, but wouldn't that give me:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
H & H \\ H & H \\ 0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $H$ are hessians for each component of jacobian respectively? How am i supposed to do taylor series with that?

Comment: What is your particular question?

Comment: How to do the second derivative of f(x,y).

Comment: Yes, but is your end goal to get the Taylor series or simply the Hessian?

Comment: The end goal are the Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to take  partial (and directional) derivatives, because they are objects of the same nature as the original function (i.e., vectors in this case). 
Indeed, 
$$
f_x(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-(R+r\cos(y))\sin (x) \\
(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x) \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
f_y(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
- r\sin(y) \cos(x) \\
-r\sin(y) \sin(x) \\
r\cos(y) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$f_{xx}(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x) \\
-(R+r\cos(y))\sin(x) \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$f_{xy}(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 r\sin(y) \sin(x) \\
 -r\sin(y) \cos(x) \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
f_{yy}(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-r\cos(y) \cos(x) \\
-r\cos(y) \sin(x) \\
-r\sin(y) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which you can evaluate at the center of the series and put into Taylor series with vector-valued coefficients.

That said, consider the alternative:   expand the trigonometric functions up to second order, plug said expansions into $f$, and collect like terms.